# sharing a single .aj AspectJ aspect among multiple Eclipse plug-ins within a single stand-alone Eclipse RCP app

Tags: eclipse, plugins, aspectj, rcp

Quick disclaimer: I am running Eclipse 3.5 and I cannot upgrade to a more recent version. I really do not want anyone to construe this as disrespectful, but please do not ask me why.

I would like to know what is the best (and kosher) way to share a single .aj aspect file among multiple eclipse plug-ins that comprise a single stand-alone RCP application.

I have seen a number of examples where a single plug-in contains an .aj aspect file in one of its packages. But I am guessing that there has to be a better way than for each plug-in project to bear its own identical .aj copy.

Isn't there a way to "centralize" the .aj file and then reference it from each plug-in project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have an aspect that is applied in several bundles?

It should work simply packaging that aspect in a bundle, and the using `Require-Bundle` from all the bundles that need it (`Import-Package` should work as well). If you need more fine-grained control, you can use `apply-aspects:=true` or `false`, for example adding this in your `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` :

```
 Import-Package: 
  com.ibm.icu.text;apply-aspects:=false;org.eclipse.swt.graphics;apply-aspects:=false,
  scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt;apply-aspects:=false
```

Make sure you list your aspects in `META-INF/aop.xml` or else they won't be executed.

Comment: You only need to place the `aop.xml` in the bundle that exports the aspects. Have a look [here](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-ide/blob/master/org.scala-ide.sdt.aspects/META-INF/aop.xml)

Comment: thank you for your response. i created a plug-in project, converted it to AspectJ project, and then used its compiler under project properties to generate aop-ajc.xml. its contents look like so:<aspectj> <aspects> <aspect name="com.mypackage.MyAspect"/> </aspects> </aspectj>. could you please let know what to do with it? should i place it within every bundle, including the one containing the aspect, or just the "target" bundles that will be importing the aspect? also, do i have to convert all other bundles to aspectj projects? thank you!!!

Comment: do i have to go to the project properties->aspectj build->aop.xml management, and then add the reference to the aop.xml under META-INF?

Comment: The `aop.xml` file should reside only in the bundle that exports the aspects. Also, the aspects bundle should use `Require-Bundle` to list the bundles that should be *weaved*. I haven't used project properties, simply edited that file and placed it under `META-INF`.

Comment: ok, i am now clear about aop.xml, but somewhat confused by the Require-Bundle. in your initial post, you stated that "target" bundles should be using Require-Bundle to "import" aspect bundle. but in your last post, you state that the aspect bundle should use Require-Bundles to reference bundles that are to be weaved. so which is it? thank you!

Comment: I think both work. We are using the second approach (`Require-Bundles` from the aspects bundle towards the ones that we want to weave).

Comment: i placed aop.xml it the aspect bundle's meta-inf dir, the package bearing the aspect has been exported from the aspect bundle via Export-Package, and the bundles to be weaved are importing the entire aspect bundle via Require-Bundle. the aspect bundle also references the following bundles via Require-Bundle: org.aspectj.runtime;bundle-version="1.6.10";visibility:=reexport,org.aspectj.ajde;bundle-version="1.6.10",org.aspectj.weaver;bundle-version="1.6.10";visibility:=reexport
and while the classes within the aspect bundle get woven, the ones in other bundles still do not. what am i missing?

Comment: i was able to make it work by first converting projects to be woven into aspectj projects. then going to project properties->AspectJ Build->Aspect Path and selecting aspect project's bin containing the aspect binary. even after removing aop.xml and aspect package export, it still worked. could someone please let me know what is the difference between what i just did and the steps described in previous posts involving aop.xml, exportation of aspect package, etc. thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be that your solution applies static weaving, while what I was describing is dynamic (or class-load time) weaving. For that to work, you need the Equinox weaving service up and running. http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/incubator/aspects/equinox-aspects-quick-start.php

Comment: could you please let me know how to go about doing that? currently, i have JDT Weaving set to ENABLED. does that have anything to do with it, or is it something different? thank you!